# Transitive permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I do not have a formal background in mathematics. However, while parsing through my lecture notes on information theory I am trying to understand the following statement.

*G is transitive if for any i,j ∈ [n], there exists π ∈ G such that π(i) = j*

If I have a set = {1,2,3,4,5}

A permutation of the set results in {4,3,1,2,5}

where  π(2) = 3 ,

Is this what the statement above means?
My confusion lies in whether i,j should be in sequence

Comment: You need to specify a group $G$ acting on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then ask whether it is transitive under the definition you quote. Just looking at a single permutation is no good.    For example the group $G$ of all permutations of the set is clearly transitive; the group $G$ of all the permutations which don't mix up the elements of $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ is not.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you, I have a better understanding now